# Is it safe for ld to interpret executables linked by gold?

Tags: linux, g++, ld, elf, gold-linker

Take a simple hello world program and compile it as follows:

```
> g++ --version
g++ 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

> g++ -fuse-ld=gold test.cpp -o test
```

Inspecting the binary produced:

```
> readelf -l ./test

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x400750
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R      8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x0000000000000ac8 0x0000000000000ac8  R E    1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000000dc0 0x0000000000401dc0 0x0000000000401dc0
                 0x0000000000000288 0x00000000000003d0  RW     1000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000000de0 0x0000000000401de0 0x0000000000401de0
                 0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000000200  RW     8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000000a8c 0x0000000000400a8c 0x0000000000400a8c
                 0x000000000000003c 0x000000000000003c  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000000dc0 0x0000000000401dc0 0x0000000000401dc0
                 0x0000000000000240 0x0000000000000240  RW     8

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.hash .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame .eh_frame_hdr 
   03     .jcr .fini_array .init_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07     
   08     .jcr .fini_array .init_array .dynamic .got
```

Notice that the interpreter used is `ld`. Whilst the program happens to work, I've not been able to find any information on whether this is safe. For all I know, `gold` interprets the ELF specification in a subtly different and incompatible way that requires a different interpreter.

I've done my best to research this, but have been unable to find anything that answers my question. The closest I've found is that `gold` struggles  to link the Linux kernel (or struggled, since time has past and it may have been fixed).

Comment: Looking at the content of `/usr/bin/gold`, you can see that the string `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is stored inside the `gold` executable. This means that the `gold` linker itself "decides" using that runtime interpreter. For this reason I doubt that there are incompatibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're falling into the naming trap — `gold` is a *link editor*, while `ld.so` is a *dynamic loader*. Although at different times, they are called *linkers* (the latter often referred to also as *runtime linker*.)

Their scope and usage is very different, the first one generates the final executable you'll eventually run, while the latter takes the generated file, finds its dependencies, and resolve (links) the undefined symbols between those.

Indeed, `gold` and `ld` (precisely, `bfd-ld`), the link editors, are provided by `binutils` (or alternative toolchain packages such as `clang` and so on), while `ld.so` is provided by the C library package, usually `glibc` on Linux distributions, but alternatively `uclibc` or `musl`.

Combining this with Martin Rosenau's comment...

> Looking at the content of /usr/bin/gold, you can see that the string /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is stored inside the gold executable. This means that the gold linker itself "decides" using that runtime interpreter. For this reason I doubt that there are incompatibilities.

... `ld.so` should be compatible with the `gold` linker.

Comment: `man ld` tells me `ld - The GNU linker` `ld combines a number of object and archive files, relocates their data and ties up symbol references. Usually the last step in compiling a program is to run ld`. It clearly says that `ld` is used to compile a program

Comment: Yes. `ld` is not the same as `ld.so`. I agree it's extremely confusing, and that's why for the past 10 years on my blog (where I wrote very often about linking and elf files) I refuse to use the word "linker" and prefer using the words "link editor" and "loader".

Comment: This is a great point - thank you. If you combine this with what Martin Rosenau said a comment on the question, this would be a complete answer to the question.